# BIAS attack on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, firmware

I am trying to recreate the BIAS Bluetooth attack on my Raspberry Pi 3. I have successfully configured it as an audio sink (to give the connection a purpose and to impersonate my bluetooth speaker) and changed its MAC address. I have also run internalblue's KNOB PoC successfully.

I am stuck on the next steps, downgrading the authentication to legacy and "manually" authenticating the device I'm connecting to. All resources online ([example](https://github.com/francozappa/bias/blob/master/bias/generate.py)) give instructions and code for a Cypress dev board, but I don't have access to one. I also don't know how to manually patch the firmware (with assembly) or at what address, or even if the same patch for Cypress works on BlueZ.

For context, my OS is the Debian Bullseye port, Raspberry Pi OS, 64 bit

It would greatly help me if you could give some advice or commands to achieve this. Thanks!